# Password Reset only by Username

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I Implimented django password reset using email but currently want to restrict to only username so that user can change password only by using username. tried [django built-in](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/09/19/how-to-create-password-reset-view.html) and [plugin](https://github.com/brutasse/django-password-reset/blob/master/README.rst) but unable to set to only username . Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: That sounds very insecure. It means all I need is your username, then I can take over your account. There'd be no point in having a password at all.

Comment: Actually all users will also have email with unique username so emailing user the based on username is still secure

Comment: In my app multiple accounts can be created with same email but different usernames so its kind of one way option to me

Comment: "In my app multiple accounts can be created with same email but different usernames so its kind of one way option to me" - Why not require both?

Answer (score 2):

Write your own reset password code. Pretty much the only code you need to write is the first step that gets the user, generates one-only link for resetting password and sends email.

Django does that with PasswordResetForm. Source code is [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py) (lines 242 - 306). Copy/paste this code to your `forms.py` (including required imports) and modify it to accept username instead of email.

In your code you then validate your PasswordResetForm and call `save()` to generate one-only link and send mail.

```
form = YourPasswordResetForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

Remember to always return success message, even if user doesn't exist and email wasn't sent, because otherwise you'll be giving out information about registered usernames.